VS Code: can't import from file after latest Pylance update. Worked before but now get "import could not be resolved"
As the title says. This was no problem prior to the latest Pylance update yesterday, as long as the target file was in the same folder.
I have looked around and learned that one can open a virtual environment. I don't know if I have to do that since it is working if I open the whole folder in VS Code. But I've had VS Code for years and I always just opened single files, never whole folders and it has always worked to import from files.
What could have happened here that I now HAVE to open the whole folder to import from a file?
and how to fix it? Is there a chance this can be fixed by itself after another update?
EDIT
The versions I'm using are VS Code 1.89.0 and Pylance 2024.5.1.
Both are the latest updates.

please add exact version numbers for pylance and VS Code.

And show us the traceback.  We can't tell WHICH import could not be resolved.

I think it's something to do with the latest Pylance update because the same thing happened on another computer after it updated on that one too

@Tim Robers: it's only when I import a class I made myself from the file it is in. All the other regular imports works fine. It can still run but it's somehow not recognized i.e it's not highlighted in VS. As I also mentioned, it works if I open the whole folder but I never had to do that before

You need to remember, when you do import xxx, it does NOT automatically search in the directory that contains the script.  If you run, say, python aa/bb/cc.py, it looks in the directory that contains aa.  It doesn't look in bb.  You can ADD that to the Python path by adding to sys.path using the path from __file__.

But why did it work before this latest update without having to do these things?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
Please see how to ask.
minimal reproducible example
